# Size of horizontal and vertical pixels in C# is different?

Tags: c#, image, height, resolution, box

My screen resolution is set to 1920x1080, but if I want to create a Form in Visual Studio with the same size, there is a big gap between the right side of the form and the right side of the screen. It only fills the whole screen, if I set the form's width to 2160.

My goal is to create a Form, which draws elements in a picture box. It's size is fitted to a landscape oriented A4 paper size, so it's height is 4x210=840 pixels, and it's width is 4x297=1188 pixels. I created the picture box with these sizes, but it doesn't really look like an A4 paper, it's width is smaller then it should be, just like the width of the form.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I assume you are referring to a UI form, but are you using Winforms or WPF? Do you have any display scaling on your monitor? And why not simply maximize the window to make it fill the screen?

Comment: Actually I have a 125% scaling, but if I disable it, the disproportion between picturebox's sides is still there.

Comment: Squareness of pixels is a monitor property.

Comment: If you want any specific physical size of your image you need to calibrate it to the physical monitor size, see [how to get physical monitor size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577736/how-to-obtain-the-correct-physical-size-of-the-monitor)